# passing value joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have this selectbox and I want to pass the value selected

I have this in my view

```
<form id="search-restaurant"  method="post" action="<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php/hardware/buscarCategoria">
<?php 
echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options ,'myfilter','onChange="this.form.submit()"','value','text');     
?>
</form>
```

I take the value seleted like this

```
$input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$value=$input->get('myfilter');
```

the value is correct but I do a print_r or echo of value

```
 print_r($value);
```

I obtain `0combo` or `1combo`
why the combo works, it is ok??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this.

http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlSelect/options

You can pass the $selected argument with proper value,It will set the default list option for you.